Updating webparts on SharePoint Online Site collection home page
I'm using PowerShell to update QuickLinks webpart in a Modern SP environment.  Updating a "Page" works just fine using the set-pnppagewebpart cmdlet.
However, when I try to use the same command on the site collection home page Home.aspx or TopicHome.aspx (I've tried both) I get an error every time.  I thought perhaps my JSON object was wrong but was able to deploy said object to a standalone page with no issue and see my updated QuickLinks.
So it seems to have something to do with the site collection home page.
Any ideas how to get around this?
The error I'm getting is the following:

224 |      Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page $MyPage -Identity $WebPartID
-Properties …
|                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PipeBinds.WebPartPipeBind' required by
parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not
| supported.

$pnpurl = "https://somesite.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST-SITE"
$MyPage = "Test.aspx"

function GetInstanceId($targetPage){
    $sitepagescontents = get-PnPPageComponent -Page $targetPage   #$TargetPage 
    $sitepagecontents
    foreach($item in $sitepagescontents){
        if($item.Title -eq "Quick links"){
            return $item.instanceID
        }
    }   
}

function CraftJSONObject($instanceID, $SitePage, $SiteURL){

    $SiteID=get-pnpsite -Includes Id
    $WebID=get-pnpweb -includes Id

    $webPartJson = '
{
    "position": {
        "zoneIndex": 1,
        "sectionIndex": 1,
        "controlIndex": 1,
        "layoutIndex": 1
    },
    "webPartData": {
        "id": "c70391ea-0b10-4ee9-b2b4-006d3fcad0cd",
        "instanceId": "'+$instanceID +'",
        "title": "Quick links",
        "description": "Show a collection of links to content such as documents, images, videos, and more in a variety of layouts with options for icons, images, and audience targeting.",
        "audiences": [],
        "serverProcessedContent": {
            "htmlStrings": {},
            "searchablePlainTexts": {
                "items[0].title": "Coatings",
                "items[1].title": "Welding",
                "items[2].title": "Home",
                "items[3].title":"Coatings"
            },
            "imageSources": {},
            "links": {
                "baseUrl": "'+$SiteURL+'",
                "items[0].sourceItem.url": "/sites/SomeSite/SitePages/Coatings.aspx",
                "items[1].sourceItem.url": "/sites/SomeSite/SitePages/Welding.aspx",
                "items[2].sourceItem.url": "/sites/somesite/SitePages/TopicHome.aspx",
                "items[3].sourceItem.url": "/sites/somesite/SitePages/Coatings.aspx"
            },
            "componentDependencies": {
                "layoutComponentId": "706e33c8-af37-4e7b-9d22-6e5694d92a6f"
            }
        },
        "dataVersion": "2.3",
        "properties": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "sourceItem": {
                        "guids": {
                            "siteId": "eb1fce43-ff96-45ce-af2f-dcf153a6fedf",
                            "webId": "964c5b1d-2b86-4d88-bb53-0648f4dd07ea",
                            "listId": "{6A7335A3-A80E-48A5-B08C-6C6D492B0C87}",
                            "uniqueId": "b1866944-036e-47a2-b87d-9646fe6becee"
                        },
                        "itemType": 0,
                        "fileExtension": ".ASPX",
                        "progId": null
                    },
                    "thumbnailType": 3,
                    "id": 3,
                    "description": "",
                    "altText": "",
                    "rawPreviewImageMinCanvasWidth": 32767
                },
                {
                    "sourceItem": {
                        "guids": {
                            "siteId": "eb1fce43-ff96-45ce-af2f-dcf153a6fedf",
                            "webId": "964c5b1d-2b86-4d88-bb53-0648f4dd07ea",
                            "listId": "{6A7335A3-A80E-48A5-B08C-6C6D492B0C87}",
                            "uniqueId": "4e277856-46c2-47ec-8176-9c6414e7d19d"
                        },
                        "itemType": 0,
                        "fileExtension": ".ASPX",
                        "progId": null
                    },
                    "thumbnailType": 3,
                    "id": 2,
                    "description": "",
                    "altText": "",
                    "rawPreviewImageMinCanvasWidth": 32767
                },
                {
                    "sourceItem": {
                        "guids": {
                            "siteId": "eb1fce43-ff96-45ce-af2f-dcf153a6fedf",
                            "webId": "964c5b1d-2b86-4d88-bb53-0648f4dd07ea",
                            "listId": "{6A7335A3-A80E-48A5-B08C-6C6D492B0C87}",
                            "uniqueId": "4345d5b8-f1a2-4ebd-b4a8-75aa008da751"
                        },
                        "itemType": 0,
                        "fileExtension": ".ASPX",
                        "progId": null
                    },
                    "thumbnailType": 3,
                    "id": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "altText": "",
                    "rawPreviewImageMinCanvasWidth": 32767
                },
                {
                    "sourceItem": {
                        "guids": {
                            "siteId": "eb1fce43-ff96-45ce-af2f-dcf153a6fedf",
                            "webId": "964c5b1d-2b86-4d88-bb53-0648f4dd07ea",
                            "listId": "{6A7335A3-A80E-48A5-B08C-6C6D492B0C87}",
                            "uniqueId": "b1866944-036e-47a2-b87d-9646fe6becee"
                        },
                        "itemType": 0,
                        "fileExtension": ".ASPX",
                        "progId": null
                    },
                    "thumbnailType": 3,
                    "id": 1,
                    "description": "",
                    "altText": "",
                    "rawPreviewImageMinCanvasWidth": 32767
                }
            ],
            "isMigrated": true,
            "layoutId": "Button",
            "shouldShowThumbnail": true,
            "imageWidth": 100,
            "buttonLayoutOptions": {
                "showDescription": false,
                "buttonTreatment": 2,
                "iconPositionType": 2,
                "textAlignmentVertical": 2,
                "textAlignmentHorizontal": 2,
                "linesOfText": 2
            },
            "listLayoutOptions": {
                "showDescription": false,
                "showIcon": true
            },
            "waffleLayoutOptions": {
                "iconSize": 1,
                "onlyShowThumbnail": false
            },
            "hideWebPartWhenEmpty": true,
            "dataProviderId": "QuickLinks",
            "webId": "'+$WebID.Id +'",
            "siteId": "'+$SiteID.Id +'"
        },
        "containsDynamicDataSource": false
    },     
    "controlType": 3,
    "id": "33887d33-011a-49fc-99ca-5e750bebfd33",
    "webPartId": "c70391ea-0b10-4ee9-b2b4-006d3fcad0cd",
    "emphasis": {},
    "zoneGroupMetadata": {
        "type": 0
    },
    "reservedHeight": 146,
    "reservedWidth": 744,
    "addedFromPersistedData": true
}
'  

Return $webPartJson


}

function Main($MyPage, $pnpurl) {
   
    
    #The interactive parm is used to support MFA login
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $pnpurl -Interactive -ClientId [SomeGUID]
    $WebPartID=GetInstanceId $MyPage
    $JSONObj=CraftJSONObject $WebPartID $MyPage $pnpUrl

   
    Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page $MyPage -Identity $WebPartID -PropertiesJson $JSONObj 

}

Main $MyPage $pnpurl


Please share the errors and PowerShell scripts you tried so far so it will help people to understand your issue quickly.

I had a leading space in my InstanceID which I was hoping to fix the issue but now I'm receiving a difference error.   | You cannot host text controls inside a one column full width section, only an image web part or hero web part are allowed
